# Blazor: How to number the rows in MudBlazor table automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor, mudblazor

I have an ASP.NET Blazor server project using **[MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/)** library to create an HTML **table**. My issue is with the numbering. In the example code below, the numbering of the rows is retrieved from the class property. However, in my class I don't have a `number` property and it's not nice to have a number property in all classes that I intend to display in tables.

Since the table accepts a list of items, is there a way of getting the index of the item being rendered and use it instead of `@context.Number` to display the row number in the MudBlazor table?

```
<MudTable Items="@Elements.Take(4)" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Nr</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Sign</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Position</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Molar mass</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Position" HideSmall="_hidePosition">@context.Position</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">@context.Molar</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>

<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_hidePosition">Hide <b>position</b> when Breakpoint=Xs</MudSwitch>
<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_loading">Show Loading</MudSwitch>
```

This example code can be found in [MudBlazor Table](https://mudblazor.com/components/table#api).

Comment: Not sure, but you can try using `@Elements.Select((item,index)=>new {Number = index, Element = item})` and then subsequent usage would be like `@context.Element.Name`

Comment: All solutions answered here do not work as expected when the list is sortable on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use index of list as it is much simpler to implement to show the row numbers in a table.

`@(Elements.IndexOf(context)+1)`

```
<MudTable Items="@Elements" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Nr</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Sign</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Position</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Molar mass</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@(Elements.IndexOf(context)+1)</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Position" HideSmall="_hidePosition">@context.Position</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">@context.Molar</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
```

Answer (score 3):

With Linq's TakeWhile you can count elements until you find element that match element of row you're currently in:

```
<MudTable Items="@MyElements">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Row</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd>@GetRowNumber(context)</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
@code{
    public IEnumerable<object> MyElements => Elements.Take(4);
    public int? GetRowNumber(object element) =>
        MyElements?.TakeWhile(x => x != element).Count();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest yet most effective method I've come out with is to use the table's `RowClassFunc` or `RowStyleFunc` property.
This method works on both client or server side data mode, with pagination, sorting and filtering.

**However, this method does not work on virtualized table!!!**

The trick is to set the row number of each items before rendering from inside either one of the above mentioned property.

```
<MudTable ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<Element>>>(ServerReload))"
          @ref="table" RowClassFunc="@RowClassFunc">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Nr</MudTh>
        ...
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        ...
    </RowTemplate>
    ...
</MudTable>
```

In code, create the function :

```
private string RowClassFunc(Element element, int rowNumber)
{
    element.Number = 1 + rowNumber + table.CurrentPage * table.RowsPerPage;
    return string.Empty; // or any class name as per existing logic
}
```

The element property `Number` is the field where the row number will be set and shown on page.

Here's the link to test : [TryMudBlazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cacdOWbbmMhHddhq)

Comment: This could be useful for server-side data mode. I will try it in future. TY

Comment: I'm on .NET 8 and still no native reference handlers. Nice hack and thanks for providing source code. While cool, I'll probably just do it the ol' fashioned (and straight forward) way and iterate over the collection of items to set an index property on the View Model. Or potentially building the rows with a loop so indexes are available to pass to methods or set attributes. Hopefully Blazor and MudBlazor evolve to provide element references out of the box. It definitely simplifies things in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a bit crude but simplest solution would be to map current number-less object to a model that contains needed number.
Create following:

```
public class Model<T>
{
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public T Value {get; set;}
}
```

Then order your original collection by some property of your choosing and iterate through, each time creating new `Model` object with consecutive Number and Value of the original object.
Use this new model as display data source for the table and all should go just fine.

```
<MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
<MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
```

will become

```
<MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
<MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Value.Sign</MudTd>
// etc...
```

Again, it's a bit crude on the eyes, but will do the trick.

Comment: Here is a fiddle demonstrating this solution: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wuGlPFmQfeUVccwD

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a counter variable and increment it for each row template
An example that I'm using:

```
<RowTemplate>
   <MudTd DataLabel="#">@(rowIndex++)</MudTd>
   ...
 </RowTemplate>

@code{
   private int rowIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: very well this works!

Comment: It works very well UNLESS you're using virtualised tables.  If you're using virtualised tables then each time the row object gets re-bound then you get a new number....